# How to customize and set some text to the slick carousel dots?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

Instead of the dots I need something like this:

[image]

See? 
I have to put the indicators above the carousel and set some text in them. That red border below the text should transition from throught the screen depending on where the carousel currently is.

Here you may see an example where you can play around:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdwQRo

Here is some CSS:

```
.main{
  width: 560px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.slick-slide{
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 310px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:999;
}
.slick-slide img{
  transition: width 0.5s;
  height: auto;
  width:100%;
}
.slick-list img{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
.slick-dots li{
  width: 25%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  height: auto;
  padding:20px 10px;

}
.slick-dots li img{
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit:cover;
  border-radius:6px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding:5px;
}

.slick-dots{
  position: relative;
  text-align:left;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use slick-carousel for this purpose? How about using Tabs/Material Tabs?

Comment: @VicJordan because I need it to be a carousel. All I need is to change the dots and set those kind of tabs there up.

Comment: Here is an example of what you want https://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/aJKbVL?editors=1010